# Why am I getting the error: Stream closed

Tags: java, http, https, runtime-error, buffer

I have been on this problem for days, I have read everything on the web, but nothing worked.

Why does my code generate this error?
How can I fix it?

Code Java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class VerifyTokenInApp
{
     String access_token = "";

    public void Check_InApp_Purchase(String productID, String token) throws IOException
    {
        CloseableHttpClient client = null;
        HttpGet request = null;
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    
        System.out.println("productID " + productID + " token: " + token);
        try
        {
            client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            request = new HttpGet("https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.my.app/purchases/products/" + productID + "/tokens/" + token + "?access_token=" + access_token);
            response = client.execute(request);
    
            // Get the response
            //BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            //  new InputStreamReader(
            //          response.getEntity().getContent()));
            //String line;
    
            //while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            //{
                // Parse the response from the server
                System.out.println("line: " + line);
                int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); //The error is here
    
                System.out.println("responseCode: " + responseCode + " responseBody: " + responseBody);
            //}
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (client != null) client.close();     
            if (request != null) request.releaseConnection();       
            if (response != null) response.close();
        }
    }

    void GetAccessToken() throws IOException
    {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;
        HttpPost post = null;
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            post = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
            ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "refresh_token"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "https://www.my.app/"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("refresh_token", "1//xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            response = httpClient.execute(post);
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            System.out.println("response: " + response.toString());
            System.out.println("responseCode: " + responseCode);
            System.out.println("responseBody: " + responseBody);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error occured due to:" + ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            httpClient.close();
            post.releaseConnection();
            response.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error at this statement: ***"String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());"***

It is good practice to close everything after use, right?

Thank you all

Comment: Please pin point your problem rather than pasting the full code here. Pls edit your question.

Comment: I believe you can't call getEntity twice because the connection is closed after the first call, but I'm not sure cause I don't know from where HttpClientBuilder came, could you provide the package name?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You are trying to read every line of the response, and for every line of the response you are getting both the response code and the enitre response. You don't need the `readLine()` loop or the stream it is reading.

Comment: @RafaelFerreiraRocha I put Imports in the code, thanks for your help

Comment: @user207421 You are right, but the answer could not be incomplete? Also don't I have to wait for the answer to arrive? (This is a new world for me, but thanks for your help, it is very precious to me)

Comment: You are doing blocking I/O. It already waits. I don't know what 'the answer could be incomplete?' means.

Comment: @user207421 Since it is information that travels in the network, is it possible that there is a loss of information?

Comment: From what I understand, my code should look like this, right?
''try  
{
 client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
 request = new HttpGet("https://androidpublisher/..);
 response = client.execute(request);  
 int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
 String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())
 }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
   System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
  }
  finally
  {
   client.close();
   request.releaseConnection();
   response.close();
  }'

Comment: You are using TCP. If there is a loss of information you will get an exception. I can't read code posted in comments. I doubt that you can read it yourself. Edit it into your question.

Comment: @user207421 I have modified the code in the question by commenting the "BufferedReader" and the "While" loop, I have tried the code and it works fine without receiving errors. Thanks man!